# Having trouble storing SESSION ID in mysqli User-Defined Variable

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Im trying to create triggers to automaticly insert data on log_tabel when users Insert/Update/Delete data from Website who is login. Im having trouble storing user_id in User-Defind Variabel @user_id.

Storing User-Define Variable:

```
$_SESSION['user_id']= $row['user_id'];
mysqli_query($dbc,"SET @user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ");
```

Trigger Code:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_log_user
 AFTER INSERT ON users
       INSERT INTO `logs` (`log_id`,`user_id`,`action`, `log_date`) VALUES 
       (NULL, @user_id,'INSERT', NOW() );
```

When i insert a user is showing error: **user_id cannot be null**

I checked MYSQL Manual : [10.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

tried same code that is in manual in phpmyadmin ("SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;") and didnt work resut :("MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0003 seconds.)")

Comment: The 2nd set query actually worked, that's the expected result what you copied in :) (set statement does not return any records). Do you reconnect to MySQL after issuing the `SET @user_id...` statement before triggering the `insert_log_user` trigger? The question has nothing to do with phpmyadmin, pls do not tag it.

Comment: the problem is at @user_id is not storing any value. I tried it directly in SQL in phpmyadmin and i`m getting result   "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

Comment: As I wrote in my 1st comment: that's what you should get, since MySQL does not return any result when `set` statement is executed.

Comment: when i select @user_id resut is null

Comment: phpmyadmin be default does not use permanent database connections. MySQL destroys user variables when a connection is closed. Use a non-web-based GUI or MySQL's command line tool to test user variables in MySQL, not phpmyadmin.

Comment: Now its storing data on @user_id but still saying "user_id cannot be null" at trigger when executed.I think i have to change method of trying to insert data on log_tabel. Thanks for the help any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Pls re-read my **first** comment...